# Update column with SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I need a query to update a column from a select (count) statement.

This is what I tried..

```
SELECT m.MaidID, m.MaidJobCompleted, count(m.MaidName) as countMaidJobCompleted
FROM  Booking b, Maid m 
WHERE b.BookingMaidID like concat("%",m.MaidName,"%") 
and b.BookingStatus="completed"
group by MaidName
```

Correct Result obtained:

```
MaidID  MaidJobCompleted    countMaidJobCompleted   
329        0                     5  
188        0                     1  
281        0                     8  
229        0                     4
```

`MaidJobCompleted` is the column I created (with default value 0).
`countMaidJobCompleted` is the column get from query above.

---

**Tables**

Maid

```
MaidIDPrimary       int(100)     ,autoIncrement eg(1,2,3,4,5..)
MaidJobCompleted    int(100)     ,default value = 0
MaidName            varchar(200) ,eg(Batman,Spiderman,WonderWoman,Indiana John)
```

Booking

```
BookingID           int(100)     ,autoIncrement eg(1,2,3,4,5..)
BookingMaidID       varchar(500) ,eg(Batman,Wonderwoman,Ironman)
BookingStatus       varchar(50)  ,eg(completed,pending..)
```

---

```
MaidID  MaidJobCompleted    countMaidJobCompleted   
329        0                     5  
188        0                     1  
281        0                     8  
229        0                     4
```

---

Now, I want to update the 'MaidJobCompleted' column according to 'countMaidJobCompleted' with UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOIN your `maid` table with your original query (becoming a sub-query) then use the `countMaidJobCompleted` to update your `maid.MaidJobCompleted` column:

```
UPDATE maid 
  INNER JOIN
(SELECT m.MaidID, m.MaidJobCompleted, count(m.MaidName) as countMaidJobCompleted
FROM  Booking b, Maid m 
WHERE b.BookingMaidID like concat("%",m.MaidName,"%") 
and b.BookingStatus="completed"
group by MaidName) t
  ON maid.MaidID=t.MaidID
SET maid.MaidJobCompleted=t.countMaidJobCompleted;
```

Comment: Although this works, it does not fix the normalization issue in the Maid table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should normalize your tables.  That means many things, but in your context I see that in table Maid, the column `MaidJobCompleted` needs to be calculated.  This is a no-no.  You could end up with out of sync values (ex. new bookings are completed, but that calculated value is not updated).  But there is a way to make sure that does not happen.  Read on...

Another problem, BookingMaidID should be a number that is a foreing key to the MaidID in the Maid table.  You are mixing the name with the ID.

What I propose to you is:

Maid table:

```
MaidID              int(100)     -- autoIncrement
MaidName            varchar(200) -- some name
```

Booking table:

```
BookingID           int(100)     -- autoIncrement
MaidID              int(100)     -- foreign-key to Maid:MaidID     
StatusID            int(100)     -- foreign-key to Status:StatusID
```

Status table:

```
StatuID            int(100)      -- autoIncrement
StatusName         varchar(200)  -- some values, ex.completed,pending..
```

---

Details:

- you should not have column values that need to be calculated.  Use queries to do that, when needed.
- the status table was added to ensure you keep control of the valid status values permitted in your booking table (and application).
- If you need to know how many completed bookings all maids have done, use this:

  ```
  SELECT b.MaidID, m.MaidName, COUNT(b.BookingID)
  FROM Booking AS b
  JOIN Maid AS m ON b.MaidID = m.MaidID
  JOIN Status AS s ON b.StatusID = s.StatusID
  WHERE b.StatusID = (SELECT StatusID FROM Status WHERE StatusName = 'Completed')
  ```
- Or if you need to know for 1 specific maid, modify it like this:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(b.BookingID)
  FROM Booking AS b
  JOIN Maid AS m ON b.MaidID = m.MaidID
  JOIN Status AS s ON b.StatusID = s.StatusID
  WHERE b.StatusID = (SELECT StatusID FROM Status WHERE StatusName = 'Completed')
    AND m.MaidName = 'THE-NAME-YOU-WANT'
  ```

Lets explain that query a bit:

- From the Booking table, you can count the number of bookings a maid as done.
- It would be nice to display the maid's name, so join in the Maid table to get the name.
- Since the status values are in their own table, join the Status table as well.

**Disclaimer** I typed in the query directly here, without testing on a sample database.

Comment: Thanks for your advises.i had read your answer more than twice. Will consider about the normalization(after learning and digging about it) ..Thanks again.

Comment: Quick and dirty normalization: `-` do not replicate the same info into two tables, link to it.  `-` Do not have calculated values.  `-` One table per object, like the status.  To avoid having things like "Complete", "complete", "Compelte", ...  Only valid values.  `-` Normal form 1,2 and 3 should always be done.  After that, it gets more complicated.